# Is there a way to create a triangular button on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

Is there a way I can create a button which is shaped as a triangle?
I know I can put a triangle image as background, but this will make the area outside the triangle clickable.
Is there a way to sey the button corners X and Y so I could make it triangular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [OnTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) Event method in a CustomView / CustomButton

Inside you have the MotionEvent were you can check if the Touch was inside your Triangle (with the help of some mathematics :P)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get exotic with non-rectangular views, then you will want to create a custom View. There is lots of information available on the web, but some of the best can be found on the Android documentation site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#custom